# bind dynamic content to DOM events drupal views

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I'm using drupal 7 to create a view and views_load_more module for load more pager
and there is a jQuery function

`$('selectors').click(function(){`

which works fine but for the dynamic content there is no effect

I have tried `.on` and `drupal.behaviors` but it doesn't seem to work
pls help me if there are any other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

seems like I wasnt using the selectors properly.
now jQuery `.on` function works fine.